# why does the scraping from a specific website not work well?

Tags: javascript, express, axios, screen-scraping, cheerio

I want to scrape all the alertDetails from this url - `https://www.oref.org.il/12481-en/Pakar.aspx`

I wrote this code but I think beacause the "In the past week" isn't Active, it can't find the alertDetails that I search for.

how can I activate the pastweek class?`

```js
const PORT = 8000
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

const url = 'https://www.oref.org.il/12481-en/Pakar.aspx'

axios(url)
  .then(response => {
    const html = response.data
    const $ = cheerio.load(html)
    const alerts = []

    $('.alertDetails', html).each(function() {
      const alert = $(this).text()
      alerts.push({
        alert
      })
    })
    console.log(alerts)
  }).catch(err => console.log(err))

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server running on PORT ${PORT}`))
```

Comment: `You don't have permission to access "http://www.oref.org.il/12481-en/Pakar.aspx" on this server.`. Do you see the class you want when you `view-source:`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use your browser DevTools to see how data is fetched when clicking on the "In the past week" button (under the network tab). It is much easier than manipulating the page HTML page.

The get the list of alerts "In the past week" you should fetch the response from `https://www.oref.org.il//Shared/Ajax/GetAlarmsHistory.aspx?lang=en&mode=2`.

To get the list of alerts in a specific date range (for example May 1st to May 7th) you need to fetch the response from `https://www.oref.org.il//Shared/Ajax/GetAlarmsHistory.aspx?lang=en&fromDate=01.05.2023&toDate=07.05.2023&mode=0` etc.

Just use the DevTool and see out going calls from network tab